# Ternary conditional not working in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

Anyone know if SwiftUI support ternary conditionals? I have a text view with conditional argument (`Text(badgeCount == nil ? " " :"\(badgeCount!)")`) that displays an empty view. Surprisingly, it works if I remove the `@State` attribute from the view.

```
import SwiftUI

struct RedBadgeView: View {
    @State var badgeCount: Int?
    
    init (_ badgeCount: Int? = nil) {
        self.badgeCount = badgeCount
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        // Something about this Syntax is throwing off SwiftUI. 
        Text(badgeCount == nil ? " " :"\(badgeCount!)")
    }
}

struct RedBadgeView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        RedBadgeView(1)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

There's no need to use the ternary operator here at all. Moreover, doing a nil check and then force unwrapping in a ternary operator is a bad idea.

Instead, you should use optional chaining to access the `description` of `badgeCount` and provide the `" "` as a default value.

```
Text(badgeCount?.description ?? " ")
```

However, your problem of the view not updating is coming from the fact that you never initialise your `State`, you just assign a value to its wrapped value. To access the state, you need to use the `_` prefix before the variable name.

```
init (_ badgeCount: Int? = nil) {
    self._badgeCount = State(initialValue: badgeCount)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Sure ternary conditions work. However you initialization of the State is wrong. You are initializing a regular Int.

```
init (_ badgeCount: Int? = nil) {
    self.badgeCount = badgeCount // >> If you initializing an Int
    self._badgeCount = State(initialValue: badgeCount) // >> If you initializing a State variable
}
```

Hence, everything will work with State aswell:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var badgeCount: Int?
    
    init (_ badgeCount: Int? = nil) {
        self._badgeCount = State(initialValue: badgeCount)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(badgeCount == nil ? " " :"\(badgeCount!)")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to other answers, if you're using **SwiftUI 2** you can do it in more *swifty* way which is to use `if-let` directly in the `body`:

```
var body: some View {
    if let badgeCount = badgeCount {
        Text(badgeCount)
    }
}
```

If `badgeCount` is `nil`, the `body` will return an `EmptyView`. However, you may return some other view as well:

```
@ViewBuilder
var body: some View {
    if let badgeCount = badgeCount {
        Text(badgeCount)
    } else {
        Text(" ")
    }
}
```

(First you need to init/assign a value to `badgeCount` to see the view).